# Python file parser - invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, string, parsing, type-conversion, integer

I'm trying to parse a file with this format

```
2010-11-04 00:03:50.209589 M003 ON Sleeping begin
2010-11-04 00:03:57.399391 M003 OFF
2010-11-04 00:15:08.984841 T002 21.5
2010-11-04 00:30:19.185547 T003 21
2010-11-04 00:30:19.385336 T004 21
```

I need to select the number in the third column. After selecting the line, I select the third field of it. Then I split it, select the type (M or T), and the number (the rest of the third field). Here the problem: when I try to select the number I get the following error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I have tried many things ( as removing an EOF or any kind of end characters) to "num" but still, I have this problem.

```
temp_sensors = 0 #total number of temperature sensors
f = open('data', 'r')#open the dataset
line = f.readline() #reading line

while line:
    step = line.split()#dividing the line into different words
    sensor_type = step[2][:1]
    sensor_number = step[2][2:]
    sensor_value = step[3]
    #print(sensor_number)
    #num = sensor_number[:2]
    #print(type(num))
    num = sensor_number.rstrip()
    appoggio = int(num)
    #print(type(num))
    if sensor_type == "T":
        if appoggio > temp_sensors:
            temp_sensors = appoggio
    line = f.readline()
print("NUMERO TEMP MAX: "+ str (temp_sensors))
```

To run the code you need a txt file data.txt with several sensor events, with the format shown previously. The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b89fbf305c4a> in <module>
 28 #   print(type(num))
 29     num = sensor_number.rstrip()
---> 30     appoggio = int(num)
 31     #print(type(appoggio))
 32     #print(type(num)) 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Please tell us which line of the input file the error is occuring. `num` seems to be an empty string - what is the value of `sensor_number`?

Comment: Yes, at the beginning I thought the same, but i printed everything (as you can see from the comment). For example, in the first line the variables assume:
sensor_number = 003 (but it's a string) 
num = 003 
appoggio creates the error. 
I thought it was because when i selected the number in sensor_numbe it adds a space at the end of the string, a space that doesn't allow to convert from integer to int, that's why i used sensor_number.rstrip(). But is doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please show what the contents of `line`  and `step` are on the loop on which it crashes. The data you have supplied will work correctly, so you must have more data that has a slightly different format.

Comment: you get the same error with `int("")` - so you try to convert empty string to number. Use `print()` to see what you have in variable `num` - and next check commands which generate this value, and use `print()` to see what value it uses, etc. It is called `print debuging`. Probably you get data different than you expect and it gives different `num` then you expect.

Comment: @KenY-N you are right. The file has 150 000 lines, I couldn't check all of them by my own. I printed and The line 1476694 the formt is wrong. There is a line in which the format is:       2011-05-10 18:42:45.169231 c OFF.           . Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the previous speakers, one line seems to use a different format. For this reason, an empty string seems to throw an error when converting to an integer. My suggestion is to test the format in advance.

```
import re

def readdata(fname):
    ptrn = r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6} [MT]\d{3} .*\s+$'
    sensor_count = 0
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i,line in enumerate(fp):
            if not re.match(ptrn, line):
                print(f'Illegal format in line {i}: {line!r}')
                continue

            dt,tm,sensor,value = line.rstrip().split(' ',3)
            sensor_type,sensor_number = sensor[0],int(sensor[1:])
            print(sensor_type, sensor_number)
            if sensor_type == 'T':
                sensor_count = max(sensor_count, sensor_number)
    print(f'Number of temperature sensors: {sensor_count}')
```